# Where to securely place files needed by PHP in Linux filesystem (according to FHS)

Tags: php, fhs

I have a PHP script running on my LAMP server that requires certain files in order to produce HTML content. The script is publicly accessible (i.e. `http://example.com/script.php`) but the files required by the script must secured. I could probably place the files in any directory other than `/var/www` and they would be relatively safe, but I'm trying to learn the Linux filesystem and I'd like to use the most *appropriate* place (according to FHS). Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't see programming question here, I think you will find more answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I guess this is more standards/security related. I'll wait a bit and if things don't pan out here, then I'll give unix.stackexchange.com a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, I think I've answered my question. The most appropriate location seems to be `/srv` (with the addition of sub-directories which properly categorize the data).

> /srv contains site-specific data which is served by this system.

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM